# ADF, dataflow - sort in expression language

Tags: sorting, split, azure-data-factory

I have an input string that was delimited by white space. In the `expression builder` I try using  `expression language` to split it. Splitting works fine as array output `[]` but issues come out when input string is not a sequence number `red box`.
Now, I need to [sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expressions-usage#sort) the array but I don't know how to use it.

The ideal condition is

```
1 2 3 4
1 3 4
1 4
2 4
4
```

but sometimes input string is not sequential number.

```
1 4 2    
1 2 4 3     
3 4 1 2
```

anyone can help me how to use [sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expressions-usage#sort) the array value ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for right now, I just tried alternative by using `iif`. So, here is some code that works

```
iif( split(LG_Pembelajaran_Guru_01, ' ')[1] == '1', true()
    , iif( split(LG_Pembelajaran_Guru_01, ' ')[2] == '1', true(), 
    , iif( split(LG_Pembelajaran_Guru_01, ' ')[3] == '1', true(), 
    , iif( split(LG_Pembelajaran_Guru_01, ' ')[4] == '1', true(), false())))
)

iif( split(LG_Pembelajaran_Guru_01, ' ')[2] == '2', true()
    , iif( split(LG_Pembelajaran_Guru_01, ' ')[1] == '2', true(),
    , iif( split(LG_Pembelajaran_Guru_01, ' ')[3] == '2', true(), 
    , iif( split(LG_Pembelajaran_Guru_01, ' ')[4] == '2', true(),  false())))
)


iif( split(LG_Pembelajaran_Guru_01, ' ')[3] == '3', true()
    , iif( split(LG_Pembelajaran_Guru_01, ' ')[1] == '3', true(), 
    , iif( split(LG_Pembelajaran_Guru_01, ' ')[2] == '3', true(), 
    , iif( split(LG_Pembelajaran_Guru_01, ' ')[4] == '3', true(), false())))
)


iif( split(LG_Pembelajaran_Guru_01, ' ')[4] == '4', true()
    , iif( split(LG_Pembelajaran_Guru_01, ' ')[1] == '4', true()
    , iif( split(LG_Pembelajaran_Guru_01, ' ')[2] == '4', true()
    , iif( split(LG_Pembelajaran_Guru_01, ' ')[3] == '4', true(), false())))
)
```

but using `iif` is less efficient when there are long array (let say `[1 ... 8]`) and must be rigorous.